# One particular DVD is not detected on Windows

Tags: windows, dvd

And sadly, it is my copy of [The Orange Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Orange_Box). I bought it 5 years ago, installed it once, got a no CD crack and then put it away. Subsequently I tried installing it again on another PC, but the system refused to detect the disk, and simply says 'Please insert a disc' if you try accessing the drive.
I get the same problem no matter where I try, and the disk does not look damaged or scratched in any way.

Is there a way to read it, or recover it as an ISO?

Comment: Please provide additional information about the operating systems in question.  My advice....just order another copy its only $15.99 on Amazon.

Comment: Windows 7 or XP, makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

If its registered with steam, you should be able to get the game installed though steam instead - try installing steam and setting up an account, then select 'Activate a Product with steam' and using the cd key there.

Using another dvd drive to see if it works would be a good idea as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten about that..though I'm not so keen on waiting through a large download (my ISP has meagre bandwidth caps).
The other (real) reason for this question is, how can one recover data from a visually undamaged DVD?

Comment: hmm. You'd still need to have the DVD detected somehow before you can do anything about it - hence my suggestion to try a different drive.

Comment: But that's what I've done so far..three different PCs & laptops, including my very recently assembled gaming PC, and the same result. All of these PCs have no problems reading other DVDs. The surface of the disk looks shiny and smooth, almost pristine since it's lain in its box for 3 years now. Strange.